# Installing Jupyter notebook locally with docker: Extra commands

Tags: docker, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I found the following [guideline](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-data-science-stack-docker-in-under-15-minutes-19d8f822bd45) to set up a Jupyter notebook locally:

```
   version:                "3"
    services:
      datascience-notebook:
          image:            jupyter/datascience-notebook
          volumes:
            - /Absolute/Path/To/Where/Your/Notebook/Files/Will/Be/Saved:/home/jovyan/work
          ports:
            - 8888:8888
          container_name:   datascience-notebook-container
```

Now I want to add one more library to this image. The command is `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet` It's explained [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#using-pip-install-or-conda-install-in-a-child-docker-image) how to achieve it with a `.Dockerfile`. However, how can I achieve that using `compose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override entrypoint in docker compose file, as this will override the entrypoint command in any ancestor of the docker file, you need to make sure you also call that entry point command.

The entrypoint of jupyter/base-notebook (root of docker image you are using) is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]
```

Adding following line in the compose file may do what you wanted to do (I haven't tried it)

```
entrypoint: [ "conda", "install", "-c", "conda-forge", "fbprophet", "&&", "tini", "-g", "--"]
```

But downside of it is that this command will run every time container is started slowing down container start up time. So recommended way is the solution you mentioned in you question